# moveit_setup_assistant cannot launch node of type in indigo

Tags: ros, moveit, roslaunch, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to start with moveit_setup_assistant

```
roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch
```

1, I have roscd to the   **moveit_setup_assistant pakage**,

but fail to roslaunch .

```
(at that time ,echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH  ---> /root/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
)
```

2,  if I do:

```
 source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash

(at that time ,echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH  ---> /opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks)
```

then, **roslaunch succeeds**!

**but if I load the urdf file in my workspace( I follow the ros-by-example-2 in Chapter 11)**,
The weird part is, the pi_robot I would like to load just **shows the two wheels in the setup_assistant window**,
it seems that it cannot find my own package
Here is the part of error message

```
"[rospack] Error: package 'rbx2_description' not found
[librospack]: error while executing command"
```

**NOTE:**

1, I have add this

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

**to the bottom of the ~/.bashrc**
and I have **source ~/.bashrc** after this so that when I echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH，the result is what  I mentioned in the statement 1 above.

2, **Below is the error message for 1st statement**,

```
root@ShawnVM:~/catkin_ws/src/moveit_setup_assistant# roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch
... logging to /root/.ros/log/90e8c606-a5a4-11e6-9533-000c290a3fdb/roslaunch-ShawnVM-31009.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ShawnVM:43182/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.20

NODES
  /
  moveit_setup_assistant (moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant]: can't locate node [moveit_setup_assistant] in package [moveit_setup_assistant]
No processes to monitor
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
```

3, I wonder if there is something wrong **due to using VM**? Something wrong with **OpenGL driver**?

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
```

4,

```
rospack find moveit_setup_assistant 
/opt/ros/indigo/share/moveit_setup_assistant
```

5, ROS version Indigo, Unbuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247531/moveit_setup_assistant-cannot-launch-node-of-type-in-indigo/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2016-11-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-09**:\

> I wonder if there is something wrong due to using VM? Something wrong with OpenGL driver?

From the error messages you've posted, this is unrelated to you using a VM. Either the nodes (binaries) are really not there, or the search path is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you really must build MoveIt from sources, please remember to run

```
source $HOME/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

before trying to

```
roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch
```

Note that you'll have to do this every time you open a new terminal (unless you add it to your `.bashrc`).

---

Edit:

> I have add this

> ```
> source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
> ```

```
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

> to the bottom of the ~/.bashrc But it does not work.

as @mpjansen correctly notes: you generally only want to `source` a single `setup.bash`. In this case, `source` the `setup.bash` of your own workspace, *not* the one in `/opt/ros/$distro`.

And a bit pedantic, but the `source`-ing probably works fine. Those two lines just don't do what you are expecting them to do (ie: cumulatively add to your ROS package path).

---

Edit2:

> I have done what you said, only

> ```
> source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
> ```

> And try again, yet it turns out that

> ```
> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant]: can't locate node [moveit_setup_assistant] in package [moveit_setup_assistant]
> ```

To avoid a lengthy process of trying to find out what causes this: can you please make sure you absolutely need to build MoveIt from sources? If not, please install the binary packages (`sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-X`), as that will make things a lot easier.

If you do need MoveIt from sources, please tell us exactly how you created, populated and built your workspace.

Also: what is the output of `rospack find moveit_setup_assistant`, *after* you have sourced your workspace?

And (to get it out of the way): you have ran `catkin_make` (or `catkin build`) *after* you cloned the MoveIt git repository to your source space, correct?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-09**:
I have add this

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
```

to the bottom of the ~/.bashrc
But it does not work.

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-09**:
I edit the post to add a bit more infomation. Hope I get some hints. Thanks

**Comment by [mpjansen](https://answers.ros.org/users/28366/mpjansen/) on 2016-11-09**:
I think you only have to add the one line to the catkin workspace:

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

This bashfile will source the installed environment of indigo itself.
Good luck

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-09**:
I have done what you said, only

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

And try again, yet it turns out that

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [moveit_setup_assistant/moveit_setup_assistant]: can't locate node [moveit_setup_assistant] in package [moveit_setup_assistant]
```

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-09**:
In official tutorial, it says it would be convenient to do this

```
echo "source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Reference to [1.6 Environment Setup, Unbuntu Install of ROS indigo](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu)

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-09**:
I follow the tutorial in ros-by-example-2,
it says there is **bug in MoveIt**, so it asks me to **apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-full** firslty,
and then **git clone something**, and **catkin_make**.
There is **something wrong**.

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-09**:
I post **catkin_make error** question  in **author's google group** and he told me the bug has been fixed, and **no need to git clone source package**.
So I **remove the source package**, **apt-get remove ros-indigo-moveit-full-*** , and then **reinstall again**.
finally **catkin_make no error**.

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-09**:
root@ShawnVM:~/catkin_ws# rospack find moveit_setup_assistant
/opt/ros/indigo/share/moveit_setup_assistant

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-09**:
Thanks for your patient reply

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2016-11-09**:
Your recommendation was right, but I missed some key procedure doing so because I am not familiar with the catkin work principle so that **I missed the procedure of remove the build and devel**

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-10**:
Good to hear you got it to work.

Perhaps consider marking your own answer as *the* answer, as that was really what made things work again.